# Remove extra Carousel-indicators in ngb-carousel and ngbSlide

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I have 3 objects in my json that I am trying to show in an ngb-carousel. The images/data is coming fine but it also has 2 additional panel that has no data. In total 5 carousel-indicators are coming. I am not able to find why those 2 additional empty panels are coming. Can you tell me how can I remove the same?

html -

```
<ngb-carousel [interval]="100000" class="frame">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let item of testimonalData;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 testimonalImage">
                    <img src={{item.img}}>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="clientQuote">
                    <p>{{item.comment}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clientSignature">
                    - {{item.nameDesignation}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="companyLogo">
                    <img src={{item.companyLogo}}>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Css -

```
.frame{
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 3.5%;
    width: inherit;
    height: 50%;
}

.frame .col-md-7{
    padding-left: 6%;
}

.companyLogo{
    height: 20%;
    width: 30%;
}

.testimonalImage{
    padding: 0%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 270px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.testimonalImage img{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: revert;
}

.clientQuote{
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 7%;
    line-height: initial;
}

.clientSignature{
    font-size: small;
}

.subHeading{
    margin: 3% 0% 3% 0%;
}
  
::ng-deep .carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

::ng-deep .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
     /* box-sizing: content-box;  */
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: rgb(177, 38, 177);
    /* border-color: rgb(177, 38, 177); */
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    /* border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; */
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;
}
::ng-deep .carousel-indicators .active  {
    background-color: rgb(177, 38, 177);
}

::ng-deep .carousel-control-prev{
    display: none;
}

::ng-deep .carousel-control-next{
    display: none;
}
```

testimonalData is Json with 3 objects